# SVG Image not Shown in WPF Application using Svg2Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg

I use [Svg2Xaml](https://svg2xaml.codeplex.com/) to display SVG image but it does not shown in the WPF application.

[image]

**Xaml Code**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}">
    <Image Source="{svg:SvgImage /UIDebug;component/Images/logout.svg}" Height="30" Width="30" OpacityMask="White"/>
</Button>
```

**DLL References**

[image]

**Import Library to Xaml**

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:svg="clr-namespace:Svg2Xaml;assembly=Svg2Xaml"></Window>
```

**Build Action**

The `logout.svg` image is stored in the `/<Project_Root>/Images/logout.svg` with `Build Action` equal to `Resource`.

[image]

Why?

Comment: Besides that `OpacityMask="White"` doesn't seem to make much sense, your code works fine for me. Does your `logout.svg` show up in a browser?